# Any way to send an xlsxwriter generated file to azure data lake without writing to local disk?

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, xlsxwriter

For purposes of security, I have a need to move a file to Azure Datalake storage without writing the file locally. This is an excel workbook that is being created with the xlsxwriter package. Here is what I have tried which returns a `ValueError: Seek only available in read mode`

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread
import xlsxwriter as xl

# Dataframes have undergone manipulation not listed in this code and come from a DB connection
matrix = pd.DataFrame(Database_Query1)
raw = pd.DataFrame(Database_Query2)

# Name datalake path for workbook
dlpath = '/datalake/file/path/file_name.xlsx'

# List store name
store_name = 'store_name_here'

# Create auth token
token = lib.auth(tenant_id= 'tenant_id_here',
                 client_id= 'client_id_here',
                 client_secret= 'client_secret_here')

# Create management file system client object
adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name= store_name)

# Create workbook structure
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(adl.open(dlpath, 'wb'), engine= 'xlsxwriter')
matrix.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Compliance')
raw.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Raw Data')

writer.save()
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your local writing limit?  Could you use a local `tempfile`?

Comment: @user1558604 I am not super familiar with temp files, but aren't they created in the directory? The security behind this is that there is data that the administrator of the server is not cleared to see and it should be as difficult as possible to obtain.

Don't want a file landing in the directory that can be captured using a script/tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is not monstrously huge, you might consider keeping the bytes in memory and dump the stream back to your `adl`:

```
from io import BytesIO

xlb = BytesIO()
# ... do what you need to do ... #

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlb, engine= 'xlsxwriter')
matrix.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Compliance')
raw.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Raw Data')
writer.save()

# Set the cursor of the stream back to the beginning
xlb.seek(0) 

with adl.open(dlpath, 'wb') as fl:
     # This part I'm not entirely sure - consult what your adl write methods are
     fl.write(xlb.read())
```

Comment: You, sir...are a god. Thank you so much. You have no idea how much headache you just saved me.

Comment: You're too welcome.  Pay it forward to help other unfortunate SO souls :)